# Unable to override a readyOnly configurable function-value object prototype property unless set to writable

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype

In the code below I have 2 properties:

- `sharedProperty` : This has a primitive type as value and is being set to just configurable.
- `sharedMethodAsProperty`: This has a function as a value and is also being set to configurable.

Now, near the end of snippet I can override `sharedProperty` just fine(with it being `readonly` and `configurable`), however for `sharedMethodAsProperty` I have to set it to `writable` else I get complaints that a `readonly` property can't be overridden. Ideas?

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var Person = function () {
  Object.defineProperties(Person.prototype, {
    "sharedProperty" : {
      value : 10,
      configurable: true
    },

    "sharedPropertyThroughAccessor" : {
      get : function() {
        return "shared property";
      },
      configurable: true
    },

    "sharedMethodAsProperty" : {
      value: function() {
      return "shared method as property";
      },
      configurable: true,
      // if we omit this true here, we can't override it below.
      //writable: true
    }
  });
};

Object.prototype.sharedMethod = function() {
  return "shared method";
};

var person1 = new Person("John", "Doe");
var man = Object.create(person1);

var sharedProperty = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Person.prototype, "sharedProperty").value;
Object.defineProperty(man, "sharedProperty", {
  value : 11 + sharedProperty,
  configurable: true
});

var sharedPropertyThroughAccessor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Person.prototype, "sharedPropertyThroughAccessor");
// bind with man, else you'd get person1's properties
var sharedFn = sharedPropertyThroughAccessor.get.bind(man);
Object.defineProperty(man, "sharedPropertyThroughAccessor", {
  get : function() {
    return sharedFn() + " overridden";
  }
});

var sharedMethodFn = person1.sharedMethod.bind(man);
// can't do: man.prototype. That property only exists on functions.
man.sharedMethod = function() {
  return sharedMethodFn() + " overridden";
};

var sharedMethodAsProperty = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Person.prototype, "sharedMethodAsProperty");
var sharedMethodAsPropertyFn = sharedMethodAsProperty.value.bind(man);
man.sharedMethodAsProperty = function() {
  return sharedMethodAsPropertyFn() + " overridden";
};
}());
```

Comment: Don't you need a setter?

Comment: @olsen: don't think so. Had i needed it `sharedProperty` would have also complained.

Comment: @deletedComment: Nope, console.log(sharedMethodAsProperty.value); is the function which i bind to man. No need to, actually can't do .get and .set because those aren't set.

Comment: @Shoaibi Where did the snippet show that the `sharedProperty ` is `writable`?

Comment: @fuyushimoya nowhere. It is not `writable`, just `configurable`. I didn't mention it to be `writable`, did i? Only `sharedMethodAsProperty` needs to be `writable` for it to be overridden.

Comment: `I can override sharedProperty without changing its data-descriptors to make it writable` what do you mean here?

Comment: `configurable` just let you able to use `Object.defineProperty` to redefined a attribute on that object, doesn't mean that its writable now.

Comment: @fuyushimoya `sharedProperty` can be overridden without changing its data descriptors. e.g. `sharedProperty` can remain `readonly` (what it is right now) and still being overriden without errors. For `sharedMethodAsProperty` it has to be `writable` to allow overrides without errors.

Comment: Assign new value to  `sharedProperty`  populates no error doesn't mean its writable, it's value remains the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82276/discussion-between-shoaibi-and-fuyushimoya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With fuyushimoya help I realized how dumb I was and why was it not working.

- `sharedProperty` is redefined for `man` object, it is never assigned a new value so that is why override works even without `sharedProperty` being `writable`.
- `sharedMethodAsProperty` is being assigned a new value for `man` object. A new `function` is being created and assigned to it. Assignment would require it to be `writable`. It'd makes sense to rather redefine it using `Object.defineProperty()`, just like how `sharedProperty` was overridden for `man` object.